# How to organise multiple Redis clients

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I'm using the [redis-sentinel-client](https://www.npmjs.org/package/redis-sentinel-client) library to manage a connection to a Redis sentinel group. The issue I have is that upon connecting I need to process records which may or may not already be present in the Redis store.

As I have two clients (due to the fact that [one is a subscriber](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis#publish--subscribe)) I am not sure the best way to organise my event listeners so that I guarantee that both clients are ready prior to attempting any operations.

At the moment I have the following:

```
var sentinelSubscriberClient = RedisSentinel.createClient(opts);
var sentinelPublisherClient = RedisSentinel.createClient(opts);

sentinelSubscriberClient.on('ready', function redisSubscriberClientReady() {
    sentinelPublisherClient.removeAllListeners('ready');

    sentinelPublisherClient.on('ready', function () {
        supportedChannels.forEach(function (channel) {
            sentinelSubscriberClient.subscribe(channel);
        });

        // Includes reading + publishing via `sentinelPublisherClient`
        processUnprocessed();
    });
});
```

(there are also `error` listeners but I've removed them to make the code easier to read)

This current approach falls over if the publisher client emits `ready` before the subscriber client. My question is how can I organise the event listeners so that I can safely call `.subscribe()` on the subscriber client and various methods (`.lrange()`, `.publish()` etc.) of the publisher listener?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply move client creation into the ready callback function.

```
var sentinelSubscriberClient = RedisSentinel.createClient(opts);
var sentinelPublisherClient = null;

sentinelSubscriberClient.on('ready', function redisSubscriberClientReady() {
    sentinelPublisherClient = RedisSentinel.createClient(opts);
    sentinelPublisherClient.on('ready', function () {
        supportedChannels.forEach(function (channel) {
            sentinelSubscriberClient.subscribe(channel);
        });

        // Includes reading + publishing via `sentinelPublisherClient`
        processUnprocessed();
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah great, thanks :-) I guess we just need a `if (sentinelPublisherClient)` around the `sentinelPublisherClient.removeAllListeners('ready')`.